# Check whether the URL has file extension or not?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

See the code below:

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-download fade">
    <td>
        <span class="preview">
            {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
            {% } %}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="name">
            {% if (file.url) { %}     //I need to check here
            <a class="btn btn-primary download"  href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>
                </a>
                                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
            {% } else { %}
                <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
            {% } %}
        </p>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
        {% } %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Now, I am checking it as a URL or not. But I want to check, whether that URL has a file extension or not. How to give the if condition?

Comment: where is jQuery code?

Comment: Any file extension in particular? It will be difficult to exclude `.com` or `.net` at the end of a domain from a file extension like `.pdf`

Comment: You can try using `file.type`

Comment: Or if you want to get the `.pdf or .txt` use this `var ext = file.name.split('.').pop()`

Comment: how to give that in if condition above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you post the wrong code? The following function will return true is the URL passed to it has a path beyond the domain name and if that path has a period.

```
function hasExt( url ) {
    var parts = url.split('/'),
        last  = parts.pop();
    return ( parts.length > 3 ) && ( last.indexOf('.') != -1 );
}
```

Example: `url = 'http://example.com/index.html'` will return `true`
but `url = 'http://example.com/'` will return `false`