# How do i extract the image extension from URL even if some URL has no extension?

Tags: reactjs

How do i create a function that extracts the .png from the URL but returns "Yes" if there is no extension such as (.png, .svg etc)?

Example URL without extension:
https://test.123.com/file/AnoxcdsffcARw

Example URL with extension:
https://test.123.com/file/AnoxcdsffcARw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646039/13331878)

```
  function hasExt(url) {
    var parts = url.split("/"),
    last = parts.pop();
    return parts.length > 3 && last.indexOf(".") !== -1 ? "Yes" : "No";
  }
```